# Data stratification for long-tailed distributions

Tags: survey, stratification

I'm encountering a few problems successfully stratifying a dataset that is long-tailed to the right.

In my research, I came across this excellent response:

[Sampling from a long tailed distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/100952/sampling-from-a-long-tailed-distribution)

which helped clarify a few things.

However, before I dive into the specifics of doing complex data surveys, I have a few questions...

Thus far, I've tried stratifying my data set of about 8000 observations into 14 strata.  This left me several strata with no counts and several with less than ten.

Reducing the number of strata (until each stratum had at least one observation) left me with only three strata in the end.

Log-transforming the data (log10(1+n)) helped increase the available strata to eight.

Running my analysis on this (log-transformed) case proved valuable.  However, of the eight strata which resulted, two only had one observation, and two others had fewer than ten:

```
    Stratum    Count
    1         3
    2         1
    3         541
    4         4909
    5         379
    6         40
    7         6
    8         1
```

So, my question is, would it be reasonable to combine the least-populated strata until each meets a minimum count (like 10)?  Looking at this data, I'd be inclined to combine strata 1, 2, and 3, as well as 6, 7, and 8.

That leaves me with only 4 strata, which seems too few.  Perhaps I could split the most-populated into two?  I realize this changes the shape of the distribution, but it still seems to be a reasonable representation.  Of course, this is the entire dataset, from which I would proportionally choose subsets of data for analysis...

I'm using this in a neural network application to predict costs of contracted work. The "cost" represents material, labor, and equipment costs which contribute to the overall value.  At this point, I'm using data stratification to help improve model accuracy before going after more data / features.  The model predictions are based on a fixed success criterion (e.g., predictions should be within 15% of target values), which improved significantly even with my modest attempt at stratification.

I'd like to take the work here to other contracted types of work, so, obviously, I'd rather not have to extensively tweak each model for each type of work (there are several hundred)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create strata however you like.  Why are you having trouble getting sufficient elements into your strata?  You can do exactly what you are asking:  combine strata until you are satisfied with the number of elements in each stratum.  Why do you think 4 strata is too few?  There is no minimum requirement for the number of strata.

My other thought is why is it necessary for your to perform stratification?  Why not perform a simple random sample or systematic sample?

Comment: I've used SRS already.  The problem is SRS misses the long tail.  The goal is to get the higher values better represented, hence my use of stratification.  Of the recommendations for number of strata, 5 to 20 seems to be a reasonable consensus from what I've seen.

Comment: So you are forming your strata around the values for some attribute that each element takes on?  Why not sample with probability inversely proportional to their value?  I think it's also important to understand what the goals of your objective are before you make any determination about whether to use stratification or not and how many you need.

Comment: See my edit (last two paragraphs).  Inverting the strata weights seems like a good idea.  As a general rule, I'd expect most other work type cost distributions to follow a similar form.

Comment: Strata weights?  There's no such thing that I'm aware of.  Perhaps you are using different terminology and that's where the confusion is coming from?

Comment: One last parting thought:  you could consider selecting strata 1,2,6,7,8 with certainty and sample from the remaining strata.

Comment: By "weights" I guess I was referring to sampling strata by their proportions.  By "inverting", the strata with lowest proportions would be the highest (clipped by the number of obs in the strata), which would gaurantee they'd all be included.  Essentially, I think it'd work out the same as your last thought of selecting the outermost strata in total, then sampling the rest.

Thanks for kicking it around.